# Problem creating a Gmail filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

*Before the new version of Gmail*:  when creating a filter, once in the pop-up window with the 11 filter options, I could always see the blue button at the bottom of the window to activate my filter selection.

*After the new version of Gmail*:  I could only see the very top of the button, but enough to still activate a filer option.  As of last week I cannot see the button at all and cannot activate any filter option.

I am using Windows 7 Home Edition.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Indeed - so simple I didn't think of it!  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While on that page, try holding down the ctrl button while scrolling your mouse-wheel. This might resize the page in manner where you can see that button again.